# knit2pdf(): knit and latex passes

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio

I'm using `knit2pdf("book.Rnw", quiet=TRUE)` to compile a book project under
RStudio.  The knit step takes a long time (I'm not yet using caching), and when
there are new references, figures, cross-references, etc. it takes several
passes to resolve them, even if the .Rnw files haven't changed.

What I'd like is an equivalent or extension of knit2pdf which allows
either `knit=FALSE` to suppress the regeneration of the .tex file, or
an option `latex.passes=` to request additional runs of `tools::texi2pdf`.

I've looked at the code in knit2pdf, and it is a bit too opaque to allow
a simple patch for this functionality.

Comment: How are you adding new references without changing the Rnw file? texi2pdf should automatically run as many times as necessary to sort out all the references. Can you describe your workflow in more detail? Something strange is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

All `knit2pdf` does is generate a .tex file and then call `tools:texi2pdf`. If you're looking for a version of `knit2pdf` that *doesn't* generate a .tex file first, it is exactly `tools::texi2pdf`.

Using `stringr::str_replace`, I do something like this and have found it sufficient:

```
knit2pdf_mod <- function(rnw_file) {
    knit2pdf(rnw_file, compiler = "xelatex")
    texi2pdf(file = str_replace(rnw_file, pattern = "Rnw", replacement = "tex"))
}
```

You could throw in a for loop to repeat the `texi2pdf` step as many times as you want.

```
knit2pdf_mod <- function(rnw_file, latex.passes = 1) {
    knit2pdf(rnw_file, compiler = "xelatex")
    for (i in 1:latex.passes) {
        texi2pdf(file = str_replace(rnw_file, pattern = "Rnw", replacement = "tex"))
    }
}
```